# No default controller available Bluetooth Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, bluetooth

## Information

My Bluetooth was working fine yesterday, but when I updated all of my packages with `yay`, my Bluetooth won't connect. Today, I ran:

```bsh
sudo pacman -Syu
yay -Syu
```

Now my Bluetooth won't connect.

When I open `bluetoothctl`, it gives me `No default controller available`.

Also, could you explain to me all of the commands that you want me to run because I don't have a great understanding of the Arch Linux, or Linux operating system? Thanks to whoever tries to help me! :)

## Debugging

I ran:

```bsh
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth 
sudo systemctl start bluetooth
```

`sudo systemctl status bluetooth` gives me:

```bsh
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: disable>
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2022-04-21 03:49:22 PDT; 1 day 7h ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 15162 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 13909)
     Memory: 852.0K
        CPU: 28ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─15162 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --compat

Apr 21 03:49:22 hashem-damrah systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Apr 21 03:49:22 hashem-damrah bluetoothd[15162]: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
Apr 21 03:49:22 hashem-damrah systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Apr 21 03:49:22 hashem-damrah bluetoothd[15162]: Starting SDP server
Apr 21 03:49:22 hashem-damrah bluetoothd[15162]: Bluetooth management interface 1.21 initialized
Apr 22 11:08:58 hashem-damrah systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Current command vanished from the >
```

Here's the output of `rfkill list`:

```bsh
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Here's the output of `sudo lsusb`:

```bsh
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 05c8:03d2 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) HP TrueVision HD Camera
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Here's the output of `sudo lsmod | grep blue`:

```bsh
bluetooth             856064  11 btrtl,btmtk,btintel,btbcm,bnep
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth
rfkill                 32768  6 hp_wmi,bluetooth,cfg80211
crc16                  16384  2 bluetooth,ext4
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A similar problem happened to me, I solved by unloading and loading the Bluetooth module on the kernel, try:

```
> rmmod btusb
> modprobe btusb
```

It may be necessary wait a couple of seconds between each command.

Comment: Thank you this solved my problem too